# How to get the value of String from one Activity to other Activity using Objects?

Tags: android, variables, android-activity, methods, instance-variables

I have two activities -ExampleActivity, Another

I want to transfer the value of `String` "beba" which is initialized as instance variable and then modified in oncreate method  to "Another" activity from "ExampleActivity" without using intent and sharedpreference

problem=the code below print value "a" (as initialized) in the log

what i want= print the modified value from oncreate method "please" in the logs

first activity

```
package com.android.example;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class ExampleActivity extends Activity {
String beba="a";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    beba="please";

    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
      b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent n=new Intent(ExampleActivity.this,Another.class);
        startActivity(n);
        }
    });
}
public String clicked()
{
    Log.i("s",beba);
    return 
}
```

here is my second activity

```
package com.android.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Another extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.another);
    ExampleActivity abc=new ExampleActivity();
    String papa=abc.clicked();
    Log.i("papa", papa);
}

}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Passing the value in the `Intent` is perfectly fine. You should never instantiate an `Activity` using the `new` keyword.

Comment: You could also subclass `Application` to create an application context, which you can access in your activities using `getApplicationContext`. This way you can have persistent objects across activities for as long as your app is running. Don't forget to set the application context in your Manifest as `android:name`

Comment: I have already used intent in my original app code, this is just an example code around the problem i am facing